# android ScrollView UI

Tags: android, xml

I am using webview in android for showing articles also the screen has next previous buttons to navigate the articles. When content is less next previous buttons must be displayed at the bottom of screen and when content is huge those buttons must be displayed at the end of content

How I can implement this? Currently I am doing something like following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:text="ARTICLE NAME"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:text="Published date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText_GRAY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/article_publish_text"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:text="FOLDER NAME"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText_GRAY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/article_folder_name_text"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/pageInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border_set"></WebView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="4px"
                android:padding="4px"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_prev"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Previous" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2px"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Next" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

for now its working correctly for large content but for short content thee buttons getting displayed right below the content and i want them at the bottom of screen

Answer (score 0):

extend ScrollView to activity , and make button visible when diff == 00 set the butoon invible only visible when schroll full page. hope it will help you.

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) 
{
    // Grab the last child placed in the ScrollView, we need it to determinate the bottom position.
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);

    // Calculate the scrolldiff
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

    // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
    if( diff == 0 )
    {

       // make button visible here
        // notify that we have reached the bottom
        Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
    }

    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below structure to implement view:

```
<RelativeLayout
.
.
.>
<LinearLayout
.
.
align_parent_top=true
id = top_layout>
//Content
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
.
.
layout_above = bottom_layout
layout_below = top_layout
.
id = web_view/>

<LinearLayout
.
.
.
id = bottom_layout
align_parent_bottom=true>
//content
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you ..:)